# Customisation of sign up page in ADB2C custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using custom policy and are have added some fields in the signup page. We have a DateTimeDropdown claim type to allow a user to select date of birth. Below is the policy configuration for the claim:

```
<ClaimType Id="birthDate">
  <DisplayName>Birth Date</DisplayName>
  <DataType>date</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="birth_date" />
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="birth_date" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/birthdate" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
  <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
</ClaimType>
```

[This is how it renders on the page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhruS.png)

The Year selection gives a range starting from 1900 and goes up to 2050. Is there any way to configure to alter or limit the values present in this dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using Predicates and PredicateValidations.
Update your ClaimType to include a PredicateValidation;

```
<ClaimType Id="birthDate">
  <DisplayName>Birth Date</DisplayName>
  <DataType>date</DataType>
  <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
      <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="birth_date" />
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="birth_date" />
      <Protocol Name="SAML2"     PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/birthdate" />
  </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
  <UserInputType>DateTimeDropdown</UserInputType>
  <PredicateValidationReference Id="CustomDateRange" />
</ClaimType>
```

Then add the following in between `</ClaimsSchema>` and `<ClaimsTransformation>`;

```
 <Predicates>
  <Predicate Id="DateRange" Method="IsDateRange" HelpText="The date must be between 1920-01-01 and today.">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Id="Minimum">1920-01-01</Parameter>
      <Parameter Id="Maximum">Today</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
  </Predicate>
</Predicates>
<PredicateValidations>
  <PredicateValidation Id="CustomDateRange">
    <PredicateGroups>
      <PredicateGroup Id="DateRangeGroup">
        <PredicateReferences>
          <PredicateReference Id="DateRange" />
        </PredicateReferences>
      </PredicateGroup>
    </PredicateGroups>
  </PredicateValidation>
</PredicateValidations>
```